# Question about math percentages

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Here's the question, Dow Jones industrial average at the close of the days trading was $12,346$, a decline of $1.2\%$

use $x$ to be the value of the Dow at the start of the day into an equation relating $x$ to the closing value of $12,346$ to determine the value which the Dow opened?

My thinking: Basically I represent $x(1.2-12,346)=$ the value?

I'm confused at what $x$ represents, is the value of the Dow that day or the initial value?

Comment: You have (100% - 1.2%)*dow(when it opened)=12,346

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says "use **x** to be the value of the Dow at the start of the day".  Then you are given that the end of day value was **12,346**.  As the value declined $1/2\%$, this is $(100-1.2)\%=98.8\%$ of **x**.  So the equation is $12346=0.988$ **x**

Comment: Thanks so much so it's using the decay factor?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by decay factor.  You are given enough information to set up an equation to find the opening value.